# Differentiable probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ with the minimim variance

Tags: functional-equations, maxima-minima, variance, functional-calculus

As the title says, I want to find a way of determining the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous and differentiable and has the least possible variance. That is, the function which minimises the functional 
\begin{aligned}
\text{Var}[f]&= \langle x^2 \rangle -\langle x\rangle^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f(x)\text{d}x -\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\text{d}x\right)^2 \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\{x^2f(x)-xf(x) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf(y)\text{d}y\right\}\text{d}x.
\end{aligned}
I know that a way to do this is to use the Euler-Lagrange equation 
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial f}= \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial f'}
$$
where
$$
\mathcal{L}= x^2f(x)-xf(x) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf(y)\text{d}y
$$
but I have no idea how to differentiate the integral with respect to $f$. I would be very grateful for some help.

Comment: Are you sure you have no other constraints? You can take $f_{\sigma^2}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ which has $\text{Var}[f_{\sigma^2}] = \sigma^2$ and then take $\sigma^2$ arbitrarily small.

Comment: Doesn't that become a Dirac delta in the limit though? I would also still like to learn how to deal with the integral even if that is the solution. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but that violates your "continuous and differentiable" requirement. I have shown that within the confines of your problem statement, I can get variances arbitrarily close to zero. However, getting exactly zero is impossible since constant random variables do not have a continuous differentiable density. So unless you change your problem statement, there is no function $f$ that gives you the least variance.

Comment: Ah I see. Is the functional stationary when the normal distribution is plugged into it though?

Comment: Just out of curiosity that is